# Unity3d generating a file in iOS and saving it on a linux machine

Tags: c#, unity, ios, linux

I've done a little research and don't know if the following is possible.

At the moment I have created a small application in Unity that generates an XML file. This file will be used to help set up my game. It's done in Unity due to it being cross platform with no need to re-write a single line of code. Eventually this will run on an iPad.

However, my game will be running on a linux computer and I need to pass over the XML file to the computer that will be running the final game (please don't ask why I'm doing that, it's something I need to do). So what I want to know is the following:

Can I generate my XML file on an iPad and have that XML file be saved, and transmitted to a linux machine, without the need to manually copy the file over. If so, how is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could open a socket from your iOS device to an app listening on your Linux box, or have your iOS app post to a web page or consume a web service that runs on your Linux PC.  Another possibility would be to use a web API for something like Google Docs or DropBox to use the cloud as the middle-man.